# Error while updating google task - Error 400 - missing task id - Alexa Skill

Tags: node.js, google-api, task

I am generating an Alexa skill. While interacting with my tasks I got the following issue:

> GaxiosError: Missing task ID

Reading the googleAPI documentation I know that I have to put the task id into the task parameter.

I have tested the function within the google API documentary and can reproduce the issue.

The documentary will need the taskID and the tasklistID. When I enter the corresponding IDs I get the same issue.

My question is, what kind of task id should I enter and where is my issue?

My code:

```
const MarkTaskAsDoneIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'IntentRequest'
            && Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'markTaskAsDoneIntent';
    },
    handle: async function(handlerInput) {
        console.log("MarkTaskAsDoneIntentHandler");
        console.log("hole sessionAttributes");
        
        const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
        const tasks = sessionAttributes.tasks || [];
        var currentIndex = sessionAttributes.currentIndex || 0;
        console.log("currentIndex: "+currentIndex);
        const currentTask =  tasks[currentIndex];
        console.log("currentTaskID: "+currentTask.id);

        var currentTaskID = currentTask.id;
            try {
                        
                console.log('Hole den AccessToken.');
                const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2();
                 const accessToken = handlerInput.requestEnvelope.context.System.user.accessToken;
                oauth2Client.setCredentials({
                    access_token: accessToken,
                });
                console.log('OAuth2-Client wurde mit dem AccessToken initialisiert.');
                                
                var responseMessage = "Test";   
                const tasksService = google.tasks({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });
                await tasksService.tasks.update({
                    tasklist: '@default', // Die ID der Aufgabenliste
                    task: currentTaskID, // Die ID der Aufgabe
                    resource: {
                        status: 'completed'
                    }
                });
        
                console.log("Aufgabe wurde als erledigt markiert.");
                responseMessage = "Die Aufgabe wurde als erledigt markiert."
            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Fehler beim Markieren der Aufgabe als erledigt:", error);
                responseMessage = "Fehler beim Markieren der Aufgabe als erledigt:"+ error;
                throw error;
            }
        
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
           .speak(responseMessage)
           .getResponse();
    }
};
```

I expect that my message ID is correct.

I tried other taskIDs and got the same issue.